# invalid origin with dropbox chooser and phonegap app

Tags: jquery, cordova, dropbox

I've added the dropbox chooser to my app like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="my app key is here"></script>

$('#dropbox-choose').on('touchend', function(){
    Dropbox.choose({
        success: function(file){
            console.log("Here's the file link:" + file[0].link)
        },
        cancel: function() {

        },
        linkType: "direct",
        multiselect: false,
        extensions: ['.pdf', '.doc', '.docx' , '.txt' , '.rtf' ,'.wps' , '.odt']
    });
})
```

it goes to load up the chooser, but I get an 'error':'invalid origin' every time

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your app runs locally so that's a security issue. What I suggest is that you host this integration on your own server, add that server to the allowed domains within dropbox and open that server page to handle the integration.